# How to detect cyclic dependency imports in react native?

Tags: react-native, npm-scripts, cyclic-dependency

Is there any package or solution to detect cyclic dependency imports in react native?

[Or]

Can I get a stack trace for cyclic imports when running the app?

Currently the cyclic dependent imports are returning undefined values, Without telling the exact issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

one simple solution is using [madge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/madge) package to check the circular dependencies in any javascript project.

run the below command in project folder

`madge --circular --extensions js app/`